# How to read .csv file from a different location in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MATLAB, I've been fiddling around to import a .csv file which is on my desktop to MATLAB. I've already tried `csvread()` function as shown,

```
M = csvread(C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/train.csv)
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

My data is in the following format:

```
Id  DV  T1  T2
1   1   15  3
2   4   16  14
3   1   10  10
4   1   18  18
```

Comment: Looks like you missed the quotation marks: `M = csvread('C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/train.csv')`

Comment: Thanks @LuisMendo, that worked, but I see the following error now
`Error using dlmread (line 138)
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading 'Numeric' field from file (row number 1, field number 1) ==>
Id,DV,T1,T2
Error in csvread (line 47)
    m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c);`

Comment: In that case your file is not a properly formatted .csv. I think it contains strings in the first row. Try `M = csvread('C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/train.csv',1)` where the `1` makes it skip 1 header line.

Comment: Can you give an example for your csv file? Maybe the first two rows?

Comment: @Nag That is a different question and so you need to ask a different question.

Comment: @Daniel, Please refer the edited description. IKavanagh, Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html) method takes a string (i.e. a `char` type) for the filename. In matlab a `char` must be expressed inside quotation marks, so this should work:

```
M = csvread('C:/Users/XYZ/Desktop/train.csv')
```